# How to get an action of topological fundamental group on the singular cohomology of a fiber?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fundamental-groups, monodromy

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a proper smooth morphism of $\mathbb C$-varieties, and $y\in Y$ is a point. I want to get an action of $\pi_1(y,Y)$ (topological fundamental group) on $H^i_{sing}(X_y,\mathbb C)$.

An idea is to get an action on the fiber directly. But it seems hard, because we don't know whether $X$ is a vector bundle over $Y$(in that case we can use paralle transport by defining a connection).

Is there any other ways to achieve it? Thanks ahead.

Comment: $ R^if_* \mathbb{C} $ is a local system, that’s how you get an action.

Comment: Is $Y$ assumed to be smooth?